# What is the difference between 'ancor' and 'ancora'?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, difference, single-words, apocope

I'm trying to learn Italian and I've seen short forms like 'amor' and 'ancor' mainly in songs. Are they used solely to shorten the number of syllables in a verse in music and can more words be shortened in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Are they used solely to shorten the number of syllables?* **Yes and no.**

If you have the opportunity to read poems or writings from the XIII-XIV century written by Italian authors like Dante or Petrarca, you will see tons of truncated words; an example can be the famous quotation from the *Divina Commedia*:

> *"Amor, ch'a nullo amato amar perdona"*

Here, words truncation leads to two advantaging factors:

1. The verse is a hendecasyllable; otherwise, it wouldn't have been and it would have contrasted with the structure of the entire *Commedia*.
2. The flow of words sounds better. This is an important thing, especially in the Italian language: many devices, like this one, are used to have a beautiful sound, when read.

*Can more words be shortened in this way?* **Of course.**

There are plenty of words that can be shortened. Nowadays, they are ruled by the modern Italian grammar rules, but in the past (like the times I was speaking about previously) poemwriters tended to shorten or transform words to have them fitting their writings.